# Teradata optimizer wrongly estimates row number then accessing to table through view with union

Tags: sql, query-optimization, union, teradata, sql-execution-plan

Let's say I have three tables: `t1`(it has about 1 billion rows, fact table) and `t2`(empty table, 0 rows). and `t0` (dimension table), all of them have properly collected statistics. In addition there is view `v0`:

```
REPLACE VIEW v0
AS SELECT * from t1
   union
   SELECT * from t2;
```

Let's look to these three queries:

```
1) Select * from t1 inner t0 join on t1.id = t0.id; -- Optimizer correctly estimates 1 bln rows

2) Select * from t2 inner t0 join on t1.id = t0.id; -- Optimizer correctly estimates 0 row

3) Select * from v0 inner t0 join on v0.id = t0.id;  -- Optimizer locks t1 and t2 for read, the correctly estimated, that it will get 1 bln rows from t1, but for no clear reasons estimated same number 1 bln from table t2.
```

What is going on here? Is is it the bug or a feature?

PS. Original query, that pretty big to show here, didn't finished in 35 minutes. After leaving just `t1` - successfully finished in 15 minutes.

- TD Release: 15.10.03.07
- TD Version: 15.10.03.09

Comment: You do aware that the JOIN syntax in completely wrong

Comment: The optimizer never estimate 0 rows

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz 0 or 1 - its not big difference

Comment: (1) For the optimizer it is (2) It is indication that you didn't describe the execution plan correctly

Comment: You're  right, but it doesnt matter )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the same number for the 2nd Select, it's the overall number of rows in spool *after* the 2nd Select, which is 1 billion plus 0.

And you query was running slowly because you used a `UNION` which defaults to `DISTINCT`, running this on a billion rows is really expensive.

Better switch to `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: You were right, it estimates the total size of the spool, which will be the same. Thank you for reminding about distinct,